How to pass array into a method correctly: cannot find symbol
I'd like to print out the names of people that do not have their time as 0, but maybe its the way that im passing the parameters that it doesnt work? I have the number of entries input as 5
Note:
I am aware of array lists but I do not want to use array lists here. I would appreciate it if no changes were made to other parts of the program aside from things regarding the array. The code doesn't have to be flexible so instead of finding out how many lines are there in the code for the array dimensions i manually asked the user to input it instead
Data stored in CSV file (in order of name,age,time):
Lana,20,6.3
Daniel,30,0
Lucas,29,4.9
Henry,19,8.2
Johnny,59,5.3

Code:
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class personProgram
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int numOfEntries;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How many entries are there in the file?");
        numOfEntries = sc.nextInt();        
                
        readFile("PersonStorage.csv", numOfEntries);

        System.out.println("These are the people that do not have their time as 0");
        timeNotZero(persons, numOfEntries)
        
    }

        public static void readFile(String pFileName, int numOfEntries)
    {   
        FileInputStream fileStream = null;
        InputStreamReader rdr;
        BufferedReader bufRdr;
        int lineNum;
        String line;
        
        try
        {
            fileStream = new FileInputStream(pFileName);
            rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
            bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
            lineNum = 0;
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            Person[] persons = new Person[numOfEntries];

            while(line != null)
            {
                processLine(line, lineNum, persons);
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
                lineNum++;
            }
                    fileStream.close();
        }
        catch (IOException errorDetails)
            { 
            if(fileStream != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    fileStream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException ex2)
                { }
            }
            System.out.println("Error in fileProcessing: " + errorDetails.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static void processLine(String csvRow, int lineNum, Person[] persons)
    {
        String[] data;
        data = csvRow.split(",");
        int lineLength = data.length;
        String name = data[0];
        int age = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
        double time = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);



        persons[lineNum] = new Person(name, age, time);


    }
    
    private static void timeNotZero(Person[] persons, int numberOfEntries)
    {
        for (int j=0; j < numOfEntries; j++)
        {
                if (persons[j].getTime() != 0)
                { 
                        System.out.println(drivers[j].getName());
        }
    }

}


Error:
error: cannot find symbol
     timeNotZero(persons, numOfEntries)
                 ^
symbol:   variable persons


In your main method, there's no persons declared. That's what the compiler is telling you. The compiler doesn't know what the symbol persons is, and it's expecting an array of Person in its place.

I had a feeling it was that, but in that case how will I be able to put the persons array that has the proper data taken from the csv files from the processLine to the main method? Since im assuming that if i declare the persons array in the main method again, wont the proper values not be in that array?

what about have readFile() return the array of persons that it has read?

I tried doing return persons in readFile() but it says  incompatible types: unexpected return value 

I'm not changing any logic with your implementation. Need to return Person[] when you're reading data from file
Person[] persons = readFile("PersonStorage.csv", numOfEntries);
Code change in readFile method
Person[] persons  = new Person[numOfEntries];
    try
    {
        fileStream = new FileInputStream(pFileName);
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStream);
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        lineNum = 0;
        line = bufRdr.readLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            persons[lineNum] = processLine(line, lineNum);
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            lineNum++;
        }
        fileStream.close();
    }
    catch (IOException errorDetails)
    {
        if (fileStream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                fileStream.close();
            }
            catch (IOException ex2)
            {
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Error in fileProcessing: " + errorDetails.getMessage());
    }
    return persons;

In processLine you don't need to send Persons[]
private static Person processLine(String csvRow, int lineNum)
{
    String[] data;
    data = csvRow.split(",");
    int lineLength = data.length;
    String name = data[0];
    int age = Integer.parseInt(data[1]);
    double time = Double.parseDouble(data[2]);

    return new Person(name, age, time);

}

Hopefully this will work for you

Sorry for all the notifs but i finally got it to work thank you so much people like you make the world a better place
